# System Calls | Read | Write | Open | Close | Linux

Tags: linux, debian, proc

In my university we should install the virtualbox and Debian to use Linux. This is done and works yet. But for the first task we should use the systemcalls open(2), read(2), write(2) and close(2). Everytime i open the Terminal and enter this functions, it doesent works.

I know this is a really stupid question, but I can't do anything with these functions.

[image: thats the open function im trying to use]

We should use the Read | Write | Open | Close that /proc/interrupts reads and outputs to standard output. How does it works?

Comment: Those are functions you can call in C. You're supposed to write a C program.

Answer (score 1):

`open(2)`, `read(2)`, `write(2)` and `close(2)` are not commands or shell
builtins, they're *syscalls* - a part of Linux API.  You can read more
about syscalls by running `man syscalls` in the terminal on your
machine and get help about each of them by running `man 2 open`, `man 2 read` etc.